# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, runtime-error

I am getting the following error while running the code.I have recently updated my xcode to xcode 7.

```
  Ld /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/cdm_reference_player.app/cdm_reference_player normal armv7
        cd /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
        export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk -L/Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug -L/Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios/dev -F/Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios/dev -F/Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/dev -F/Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/release -filelist /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Intermediates/cdm_player_ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/cdm_reference_player.build/Objects-normal/armv7/cdm_reference_player.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaAsyncSocket.a /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCocoaHTTPServer.a /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libTBXML-iOS.a -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework Foundation -framework Security -framework UIKit -framework oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_dev_dylib -framework oemcrypto_tfit2_dev_dylib_sim -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Intermediates/cdm_player_ios.build/Debug-iphoneos/cdm_reference_player.build/Objects-normal/armv7/cdm_reference_player_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/anurajennai/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cdm_player_ios-cvwkkaawlnzyccamzriqmgoezgqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/cdm_reference_player.app/cdm_reference_player

    ld: '/Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/release/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

***EDIT***
[image]

see this image.In the error log,it says

```
oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib' does not contain bitcode
```

do which one do I have to set "NO" and which one to "YES"?

**after changing BITCODE setting(if both debug and release are NO,the same error is coming)**
[image]

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/release/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/release/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios/dev/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_dev_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_dev_dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios/dev/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_dev_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_dev_dylib (2 slices)
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/oemcrypto_tfit2_dev_dylib_sim.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2_dev_dylib_sim) for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Its a library that i need to add to my project.Do you know the reasons for this error?

Comment: In Xcode Under build settings search bitcode and then see if it is set to "NO", change it to "YES"

Comment: Check in your added framework too. give them a try with both "YES" or "NO" Values. For CocoaPods it should be "NO" and for Apple Watch apps it should be "YES".

Comment: try to change debug value to YES

Comment: No,it don't help.The error has changed.see the updated question.Thanks for your time by the way bro.

Comment: which library you are trying to use?

Comment: Its an encrypted video player library.Now the error is related to architecture i386..any idea about that?

Comment: there must be some name of the lib...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have already solved problem with Bitcode, so my  answer only about last error messages:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/anurajennai/Desktop/myApps/unziped/cdm_player_xcode_template/oemcrypto_tfit_ios_dylib/release/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
```

means that lib doesn't have i386 arch (can't be used on simulator) try build for iOS device

second one:

```
ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later
```

but I see that in your project:

```
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
```

deployment target set to 7.0 so you should decide something with it

Comment: Now that I run the code on a device with iOS 7,it gives me the following error.ld: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib) for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)..

Comment: Does that mean that  need a real iOS 8 device to run the code?

Comment: yes, this means that you need real device to run, and second, can you try to set deployment target to 8.0 and build project for iOS device (not run, just build) to see what happened

Comment: Now I can build the file(ipad ios 9).but the launscreen appears and then the app crashes with following error.dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F66576CC-C63A-42CC-A7B3-AE168B9CE86B/cdm_reference_player.app/cdm_reference_player
  Reason: image not found...Can you help me with that?

Comment: If I'm remember right, framework should be copied and installed with app, there are section in project settings->build phases->copy files, if no you can add it, or google a bit about dynamic frameworks

Answer (score 2):

`oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib`

Doesn't contain bitcode, either ask the vendor of this library to provide bit code or disable bitcode for this project

Please read the error message again:

> 'oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib.framework/oemcrypto_tfit2-eit_release_dylib' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7